# fscanf decimal output giving strange values

Tags: c, fwrite, scanf

I am writing a C program to read in details of a student to a structure and then write it to a file. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char String[20];

struct student {
    char firstName[15];
    char lastName[20];
    int age;
    int gradeLevel;
    double GPA;
    int noClasses;
    char classes[20];
    double grades;
    char enrollDate[20];
    char gradDate[20];
};

typedef struct student Student;
    
int main() {

    FILE *sfPtr;
    char fileName[256];
    int i, studentSize;
    struct student collegeStudents = {"", "", 0, 0, 0,
            1, "", 0, "", ""};

    puts("Enter File Name:");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    if ((sfPtr = fopen(fileName, "rb+")) == NULL) {
        puts("File could not be opened.");
    } else {
        puts("Enter number of students:");
        scanf("%d", &studentSize);

        for (i = 0; i < studentSize; i++) {
             fscanf(stdin, "%14s%19s%2d%1d%2lf%1d%19s%5lf%19s%19s",
                    collegeStudents.firstName,
                    collegeStudents.lastName,
                    &collegeStudents.age,
                    &collegeStudents.gradeLevel,
                    &collegeStudents.GPA,
                    &collegeStudents.noClasses,
                    collegeStudents.classes,
                    &collegeStudents.grades,
                    collegeStudents.enrollDate,
                    collegeStudents.gradDate);

            fseek(sfPtr, i * sizeof(struct student), SEEK_SET);

            fwrite(&collegeStudents, sizeof(struct student), 1, sfPtr);
        }
        fclose(sfPtr);
    }
}
```

When I run it and enter 's' for the strings and 1 for the ints and doubles, it gives weird values for the ints and doubles. Here is the file result:

> s              s                                    ð?   s
> ð?s                   s

Am I missing something?

Comment: What are you expecting a non-text file to look like when opened with a text editor? For comparison try opening your program or object files with a text editor.

Comment: You're writing a binary file, not a text file. You're seeing what the binary representation of numbers looks like when interpreted as text.

Comment: If you want to write the numbers in text, use `fprintf()`. Writing to files using `fwrite()` dumps the content of the buffer.

Comment: check return value of `fscanf`

Comment: this line: `typedef char String[20];`  means that every time that the code says 'char' it will be replaced with 'String[20]`   That is NOT what you want.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value ( not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the "%s" input/format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer so the user cannot overflow the buffer.  Such overflow results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when outputting an error message, it should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   When the error indication came from a system, function, also output the message from the system as to why it thinks the error occurred.  The easiest way to do that is: `perror( "fopen for read of file failed" );`   and generally, that should be followed by the statement: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are defined in the `stdlib.h` header filel

Comment: since you are writing the students sequentially to the output file, no need to be re-positioning the file pointer, so the call to `fseek()` is not needed.   The posted code not reading that file so the `+` is not needed in the call to `fopen()` mode parameter

Comment: when calling `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, be sure to call `fclose()` on the output file

Comment: when calling the function: `fscanf()` it would be better to have the format string (second parameter) be: `"%14s %19s %2d %1d %2lf %1d %19s %5lf %19s %19s"` so the function handles any 'white space' before any input field

Comment: when declaring the struct student, there is no need to initialize the fields as every field is updated every time via the call to `fscanf()`

Comment: this line: `typedef struct student Student;` is not needed as the name `Student` is not used anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: when calling `fwrite()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  The returned value should be the same as the 3rd parameter, other wise some problem has occurred.

Comment: I was writing a binary file instead of a text file, so thank you for clarifying that. I know what to do now